# React Native Failed to install the app Error

Tags: react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0E1h.png)

I can't seem to solve why this is happening, i ran through all guides and possible solutions posted. It does launching the emulator after i type command 'npx react-native run-android' but after i get this error. I have no idea at this moment please help

I ran npm, i can successfully start the JS server. I also did everything on the guides (SDK, Virtual device requirements etc.) But it just won't install the app to the emulator.

Comment: What is the output of running react-native-doctor?

Comment: which command you used for run android

Comment: if you use "react-native run-android" So you need to use "npx react-native run-android"